# The webpage is in JS but still text browsers are reading the content. How is it?

Tags: seo, html, javascript

I was checking the site giftedandtalented.com. first of all the the source code is so cluttered. 
When i disabled the JS in my browser, except for top navigation nothing showed up but when i checked the site in text browser, the content showed up. How did that happen. does it have an alternate way of reading the site content? my intention was to check if the content is read-able by Google but webcache was not showing up.

why some websites have such cluttered source code?

Comment: Is JS disabled in the text browser?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not **[about a website you control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**. This type of question is better suited for [chat].

Comment: Thank you for the answers. It is about Seo and crawling hence I asked here. Thank you for suggesting the right group. Will check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disable CSS, you’ll see the content. So the content is hidden within CSS, without any JavaScript involved (and will likely get displayed via CSS if JavaScript is enabled).

Even if the content would only be shown with JavaScript, note that there are text browsers that run JS. See for example these Stack Exchange questions:

- [Is there a text mode browser which supports javascript?](https://askubuntu.com/q/34687/82665)
- [Text based browser that runs JavaScript](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11678/60)
- [Text based webbrowser that supports JavaScript?](https://superuser.com/q/299190/151741)
- [Command line browser with js support](https://superuser.com/q/448514/151741)

Answer (score 0):

If disabling javascript breaks the site, it obviously means that part of the site is dependent on the script.

As for messy code?  It doesn't matter as long as it works.  Perhaps it is to make it a little more difficult to 'steal' code.  Perhaps it is a lazy programmer.  Perhaps the site is dynamically created and they haven't put in the work to format the code properly.

It makes no difference to a browser, and that is all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

The site has on the one side noscript areas, which provide content in case javascript is off.

> when i checked the site in text browser, the content showed up

On the other side it is possible to deliver the content (and even completely different sites) based on user agent. So if text browser is recognized as a specific user agent, the server could deliver a special site's version, build for such cases.